# react native useState is not incrementing counter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When counter is >= data Array length setLoading should trigger. But counter is not being incrementing until I refresh app by pressing CTRL+S then counter increment itself by 1 every time app refreshes.

```
const [loopCount, setLoopCount] = useState('1');
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    const getPackages = async () => {
       try {
         const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
         if (offerings.current !== null) {  
           var counter = 0;
           data.forEach((category, index) => { //data is array with length of 6
            if(category.entitlement_id){
                AsyncStorage.getItem(category.entitlement_id).then((value) => {
                  console.log("Loop COUNT before is : "+loopCount);
                  setLoopCount(loopCount+1);  //This should increment on every iteration of forEach
                  console.log("Loop COUNT after is : "+loopCount);
                });
            }else{
              console.log("ELSE COUNTER" + counter);
              setLoopCount(loopCount+1);
            }
            if(loopCount >= data.length){  //if counter is >= data length do something
              setLoading(false);
            }
         })
       }else{
        console.log("No offerings found");
       }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error => " + e);
    }
  }

  getPackages();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating state is an asynchronous operation, so getting `loopCount` in for loop will get the initial `loopCount` value instead of updated value. If you don't need UI update for updating `loopCount`, you can use `useRef` instead of `useState`:

```
const loopCount = useRef(1);
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    const getPackages = async () => {
       try {
         const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
         if (offerings.current !== null) {  
           var counter = 0;
           data.forEach((category, index) => { //data is array with length of 6
            if(category.entitlement_id){
                AsyncStorage.getItem(category.entitlement_id).then((value) => {
                  console.log("Loop COUNT before is : "+loopCount.current);
                  loopCount.current = loopCount.current+1;  //This should increment on every iteration of forEach
                  console.log("Loop COUNT after is : "+loopCount.current);
                });
            }else{
              console.log("ELSE COUNTER" + counter);
              loopCount.current = loopCount.current+1;
            }
            if(loopCount.current >= data.length){  //if counter is >= data length do something
              setLoading(false);
            }
         })
       }else{
        console.log("No offerings found");
       }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error => " + e);
    }
  }

  getPackages();
}, [])
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: useRef

Comment: `import {useRef} from 'React'`

Comment: and why can't you just use the `counter` variable declared locally?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the counter is really necessary here, I would suggest a solution with synchronious AsyncStorage.getItem

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  const getPackages = async () => {
    try {
      const offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();
      if (offerings.current !== null) {
        var counter = 0;

        await Promise.all(
          data.map(async (category, index) => {
            if (category.entitlement_id) {
              await AsyncStorage.getItem(category.entitlement_id).then(value => {
              });
            } else {
              console.log('ELSE COUNTER' + counter);
            }

          })
        );

        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        console.log('No offerings found');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Error => ' + e);
    }
  };

  getPackages();
}, []);
```